# What is the Filtering / Mapping order of exception handled by ExceptionMapper?

Tags: java, exception, jax-rs

Having in my application:

- 1 CustomBusinessException (extends Exception)
- An exception mapper A for exception type 'CustomBusinessException'
- An exception mapper B for exception type 'Exception'

Is there an order in the exception mapping management?
For example, what happens if:

- my application throws a CustomeBusinessException: handled by mapper A or B ?
- my application throws a generic Exception (or any other extending this class): handled by A or B ?

Answer (score -2):

From my personal experience, Jersey will map the most specific subclass specified by any **ExceptionMapper** implementation.

In the case of your **CustomBusinessException**, the exception mapper used should be mapper A because mapper A is specific about the class type.

For generic exceptions, such as the **Exception** class or any other sub-classes of **Exception**, mapper B will be used.

Subsequently, you can let **CustomBusinessException** extend **WebApplicationException** as follows:

```
public class CustomBusinessException extends WebApplicationException
{
  public CustomBusinessException() {        
     super(Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).build());
  }
}
```

The above creates a response that is processed by Jersey and is more easily consumed by clients.